# Accordion menu doesnt appear in frontpage

Tags: wordpress, menu, accordion

my site is [www.imblasco.cl](http://www.imblasco.cl)

Im having trouble with accordion menú in my frontpage, it appears Missing Accordion Menu configuration. This happened alone, no changes in accordion settings have been done. Please your help for it to appear once again.

Some minor tests in accordion menu settings which didnt work.

Comment: Welcome! Please read why [offsite links are not good](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80978/questions-linking-to-external-web-sites-instead-of-showing-code). We also have no idea what theme you're using, plugins, custom code, etc.. As of right now, this question is unanswerable.